# Django check for duplicated content_type and object_id

Tags: django, django-models

I need to check records being added for the same (content_type and object_id) to make sure non are duplicated to the database when being saved.

```
  class objectHere(models.Model):
        """
        Notes:


        See: http://www.screamingatmyscreen.com/2012/6/django-and-generic-relations/
        """
        content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, help_text="Represents the name of the model")
        object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(help_text="stores the object id")
        content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

        reason = models.CharField(max_length=60)

        request_made = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,
                                       help_text="Shows when object was created.")
```

i was thinking of doing something with pre_save? Can this be done, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it in one of multiple ways i can think of:

1. The `pre_save` signal
2. Override the Models' `save()` method
3. Adding a unique constraint on the models' `Meta` property.
4. Check it in the view or the form's clean method

The cleanest approach would be to use the [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together)  on the Model's `Meta`. However, if you do not want to run a migration against the models,  I would recommend the view/form's clean method if there is some user action that would be required for addressing the error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [`unique_together` meta option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together) on your model:

```
class MyObject(models.Model): 
    content_type = models.ForeignKey()
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    ....

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["content_type", "object_id", ]
```

Comment: @AnkitJaiswal - A list works too .. Tuple is just an immutable representation of a list

Comment: @karthikr Ah! ok, did'nt know that tuple also works there. Just saw the documentation and commented here.